# Specify a $default API Gateway stage via CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm using [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html).

From the docs, I see *"Stage names can contain only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and underscores, or be $default."*

But when I try:

```
Resources:
  ExpressApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: '$default'
```

The stack create fails with message:

> Stage name only allows a-zA-Z0-9_

I just want to be able to use the API base URL without the StageName in the path. My API has only one stage.

Is there a way to do that without hooking up a custom domain to the API?

Comment: Are you creating a Rest Api or Http Api ? if its Rest api, stage name is just `default` , if its Http Api , it need not be given, by default it creates `$default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html):

StageName is optional as HTTP API creates `$default` stage by default which can be accessed without any prefix and auto deployes.

> If no name is specified, AWS SAM uses the
> $default stage from API Gateway

For [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html)

StageName is required. There is no auto deploy for Rest APIs. SAM Template behind the scenes it creates that stage and deploy code to that stage and it allows only `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Comment: Hi. This is `AWS::Serverless::Api` which is REST API. Can you eliminate stage name from URL of the rest api? I think this is the OPs question?